# Script called from ~/.ssh/config loses TTY

Tags: stty, password-less, ssh-config

I'm using a site-specific authentication script that issues a 24-hour certificate for password-less login. What I'm trying to do is rig my `~/.ssh/config` so `ssh` triggers the script if the certificate has expired:

```
Match originalhost remotehost.site exec "test $(file.age ~/.ssh/certificate) -ge 86400" exec ~/bin/authentication_script
```

This **almost** works -- it tests the age of the latest certificate file ok, and invokes the `authentication_script` if it's out-of-date. The problem is that this script is using TTY `read` operations to take the password input, and giving these errors:

```
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
authentication_script: The sshproxy server said: Authentication failed. Failed login: myname: 
authentication_script: This usually means you did not enter the correct password or OTP: 
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
authentication_script: The sshproxy server said: Authentication failed. Failed login: myname: 
authentication_script: This usually means you did not enter the correct password or OTP: 
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

This doesn't happen when I run the script on the command-line from a regular login session.
Is there some mode that I can flip to get it to work?

Comment: Using ```ssh -t remotehost.site``` doesn't work either. It may solve the problem when the I/O operations are happening through the ssh-connection; what's going on here, though, is ```ssh``` is invoking the script *locally* on my laptop and seems to be following a different set of re-direction rules.

Comment: The script uses the form


```read -r -p "Enter the password for ${user}: " -s pw```

I'm hoping that I could add the

```-u fd  Read input from file descriptor fd```

somehow, to re-connect the input to my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that `exec` disables the `stdin`/`stdout`, and referred to here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674759/how-to-make-ssh-config-match-host-exec-inherit-current-shells-tty-name

But for my purposes, I am able to use PTY operations to control the I/O:

```
 PTY=$(ps --no-headers $$ | xargs index 2)
 printf "Enter the password}: " > /dev/$PTY
 read -r -s pw < /dev/$PTY
```

(The `index` operation is just my script to return the nth item from a list)